# How to edit .csv header row

Tags: php, csv, row, edit

I´m using a script to export Products from a shop to one .csv file.
Now I need to change the header row to make it work for me.

I was searching a long time but didn't get it how to make it work.
maybe I'm just to silly for that.

Lets say my CSV looks like this:

1. Heading1 Heading2 Heading3
2. value1   value2   value3

Now I need to open that csv file, change just the Headings, close and save it.

Comment: "Now I need to open that csv file, change just the Headings, close and save it."  Notepad maybe?

Comment: Need to make it with php...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$f = "file.csv";

$new_heading =  "World,Mama,Euro";
$new_heading.="\n";

// read into array
$arr = file($f);

// edit first line
$arr[0] = $new_heading;

// write back to file
file_put_contents($f, implode($arr));
```

Comment: That worked for me! Thanks!
Can you tell me how to delete, lets say the second column with all entries in it?

Comment: that is a diferent question, is a litle more dificult to use this same code here...