# How can I replace ";" for "," in a weird CSV file

Tags: php

I have a weird CSV file. It has these characteristics:
- The first line (headers) are seperated by a semicolon ;
- All the rest is seperated by a comma ,
- The file is in ISO-8859-1 format

I can read the file, but I do an external conversion first, namely

```
"sed -i 's/;/,/g' " . $arg1;
```

That is depending on my linux shell and works fine locally. But I want it more robust and convert it within PHP so that the first line headers are sepeated with a comma too (and the output is UTF-8 if possible)

Any sugestions how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to edit .csv header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618065/how-to-edit-csv-header-row)

Comment: Also worth taking a look at; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374425/convert-utf8-characters-to-iso-88591-and-back-in-php

Comment: You really don't even need to edit the first row. You can specify the delimiter for [`fgetcsv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) (third option), so for the header row specify the semi-colon, and use comma for all the rest.

Comment: The C in CSV stands for 'Character', not comma, and Excel uses `;` which is a perfectly valid choice. Blanket-replacing commas and converting charsets is going to cause problems for you down the line. You _should_ be feeding the necessary extra parameters to your decoder so that it can just read the file as-is.

Comment: @Sammitch Actually, it really does mean Comma, just as a TSV is tab-separated values. Someone somewhere along the way decided to use other characters and still called it a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the 1st line you could use a `str_replace()` on the 1st line. If the file is huge (otherwise why not use a text-editor), then you could progressively read it, to dump all the rest of the lines to the dest file as opposed to bringing the source file all into memory with `file()` or the like.

Edit:

Would love to hear the down voter's own solution.

Edit 2:

In PHP using str_replace() for the 1st line.

```
$lines = file($source, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$lines[0] = str_replace(";", ",", $lines[0]);


// DONE

// Output to dest or original
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but I assume it's because you suggested running `str_replace` when there are far better solutions, such as what @aynber mentioned in the OP

Comment: @isThisJavascript. The OP's requirements are that its affecting one line. Are you suggesting a performance hit on using str_replace() on one line?

Comment: As I said, I didn't downvote I can only assume. I'm not inclined to upvote because I honestly think this was a poor question from the start.

Comment: I understand. The idea in of itself -- making your own utilities -- I can respect that is why I answered.